# Function echartR not found in package recharts

Tags: r

"could not find function "echartr""received when i run the function "echartR".
anybody who can help me, i tried many times.
this is my code:

```
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github('cosname/recharts')
library(recharts)
## basic plot 01 sccatter plot
echartr(iris, x=Sepal.Width, y=Petal.Width, series=Species)
```

Answer (score 0):

`echartr` is not a function of the `recharts` package.
If you need to draw a scatter plot, use this:

```
library(recharts)
ePoints(iris, xvar=~Sepal.Width, yvar=~Petal.Width, series=~Species)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

echartr is a function of the recharts2 package. https://github.com/madlogos/recharts2

Reinstall recharts, call the library and rerun your codes or try the sample code below.

```
devtools::install_github('madlogos/recharts')
library(recharts)
titanic <- data.table::melt(apply(Titanic, c(1, 4), sum))
names(titanic) <- c('Class', 'Survived', 'Count')
echartr(titanic[titanic$Survived == 'Yes', ], Class, Count) %>%
setTitle('Titanic: N Survival by Cabin Class')
```

and the results will be something like
[Your Bar/Column Chart is nice and shiny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm40f.png)